# How to create a message with plain-text format in Outlook?

Tags: ms-office

When I create a message in [mail.app](/questions/tagged/mail.app) I can toggle it to plain text. How can I do the same with “Outlook for Mac”? Basically I’d like the feature described by [this Microsoft help page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-message-format-to-html-rich-text-format-or-plain-text-338a389d-11da-47fe-b693-cf41f792fefa), but this page is for Windows.

Background: plain text email is typically strongly encouraged in OSS (open-source software) community.

Comment: Isn't this in the same place in the Mac version as it is in Windows?

Comment: @nohillside Nope. The menu in Mac is totally different from Windows version. The menu items mentioned in that help page doesn’t exist in the Mac version at all.

Comment: I ended up using [tag:mail.app] instead, but I’d still love to know whether Outlook has this feature.